# sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Tags: arrays, fetch, sqlsrv

I found an old project and somehow, it doesn't work anymore? I mean really, we closed it working and now it isn't anymore.

```
    function fetchCharacter($UserNo){
        $connection_array = array( "Database"=>"Character", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"Password");
        $testcon = sqlsrv_connect("D-PC\SQLExpress", $connection_array);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tCharacter WHERE nUserNo = ? AND bDeleted = ?";
        $param = array($UserNo, 0);
        $characters = sqlsrv_query($testcon, $sql, $param);

        while($character = sqlsrv_fetch_array($characters, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
```

So I really don't know what is wrong there. I get the error for `sqlsrv_query` and for `sqlsrv_fetch_array`.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: That error tends to suggest that your connection `$testcon` is `false` meaning your connection has likely failed. You can try printing any errors using `die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));`

Answer (score 0):

You should look for errors after `sqlsrv` functions.

```
function fetchCharacter($UserNo) {
    $connection_array = array( "Database"=>"Character", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"Password");

    $testcon = sqlsrv_connect("D-PC\SQLExpress", $connection_array);

    if (!$testcon) {
       die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tCharacter WHERE nUserNo = ? AND bDeleted = ?";
    $param = array($UserNo, 0);
    $characters = sqlsrv_query($testcon, $sql, $param); // telling $stmt instead of $characters could be less confusing

    if( !$characters ) {  
       die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    $character = sqlsrv_fetch_array($characters, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($character === FALSE) {
       die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    } else if ($character === NULL) {
       // no result from select
       return;
    }

    do {
       // some operations
    } while($character = sqlsrv_fetch_array($characters, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC));

    ...
```

References

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-connect
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-query
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-fetch-array